# Weird texture binding bug on Mali-400 MP

Tags: opengl-es

On Mali-400 MP, there's a weird bug with texture binding.

Sometimes, shaders use textures from wrong samplers.

On other mobile and desktop GPUs, the same code works fine, but on Mali, almost every draw call is broken:
[image]

As you see, lightmap texture (at sampler 6) is used instead of diffuse texture (0).

Anyone knows a workaround to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was an issue with the driver not compiling `uniform sampler2D u_LightmapTexture[MAX_LIGHTMAPS]` correctly.

Unrolling the array of `sampler2D`s fixed the issue.

Comment: Of course! Also, on Adreno (tested on driver 45.0), uniform struct arrays don't work, all struct fields point to the first one.